# Unable to filter dataframe due to datatype issues in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis

I am working on covid19.analytics data and have created a **long form of dataframe**.

```
head(data_gather)
```

Result

```
date        Country  Count
<date>      <fctr>   <dbl>

2020-01-22  US       1      
2020-01-23  US       1      
2020-01-24  US       2      
2020-01-25  US       2      
2020-01-26  US       5
```

```
class(data_gather)
"data.frame"
```

I am trying to filter the countries that have covid cases **Count > 300000** and then work with resulting countries. I am using below line of code **to filter out unique country names** which is working perfectly and **gives me 11 country names**.

```
unique(data_gather[data_gather$Count > 300000,]["Country"])
```

Results

```
    Country
    <fctr>
            
74   US         
316  Brazil         
533  India          
705  Russia         
1163 United Kingdom
```

class of above code results

```
class(unique(data_gather[data_gather$Count > 300000,]["Country"]))
"data.frame"
```

#### Problem:

When I include above **line of code inside a filter then it doesn't work**. I have tried running below options but none is working and all returning 0 rows:

```
data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% unique(data_gather[data_gather$Count > 300000,]["Country"]))

data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% as.character(unique(data_gather[data_gather$Count > 300000,]["Country"])))

data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% as.vector(unique(data_gather[data_gather$Count > 300000,]["Country"])))

data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% as.list(unique(data_gather[data_gather$Count > 300000,]["Country"])))

data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% lapply((unique(data_gather[data_gather$Count > 300000,]["Country"]) ), as.character)
```

But when I try below code then I get the desired results:

```
data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% c("India","US","Brazil"))
```

I don't want to hard code the name of the countries and filter dataframe based on condition only but I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code and how to fix or optimize ?

#### After optimizing abit I am still having issues:

```
top_countries <- data_gather %>% 
  filter(Count > 300000) %>% 
  distinct(Country)

data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% top_countries))

# this also doesn't work
data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% as.vector(top_countries)))
```

### Finally it worked after suggestions by @akrun

```
data_gather %>% 
  filter(Country %in% pull(top_countries)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first `filter` by the 'Count' and get the `distinct` 'Country

```
library(dplyr)
data_gather %>%
       filter(Count > 300000) %>%
       distinct(Country)
```

Comment: thanks @akrun. This works and is also a neat way of doing it but I am still confused why my code is not working ?

Comment: @ViSa INstead of subsetting the whole dataset and then returning a single column data.frame, I would have return a `vector` with `[[`

Comment: I have used your code but I am still facing the same issues of returning 0 rows. I have added those line of codes at the bottom of the question. Even if I convert this into vectors it still returns the same.

Comment: @ViSa What is the output of `data_gather %>% 
  filter(Count > 300000)`

Comment: @ViSa then with `distinct(Country)` it is returning 0?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understan when you said it is returning 0 rows

Comment: It returns 0 rows when I try following code 

`top_countries <- data_gather %>%  filter(Count > 300000) %>% distinct(Country)`

`data_gather %>% filter(Country %in% top_countries)`

Comment: @ViSa You need to `pull` the 'Country` as a vecotr i..e `filter(Country %in% top_countries %>% pull(Country))`